# My arrow keys aren't working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

My arrow keys aren't working on my laptop. It used to work in Windows 8.1, but not in Ubuntu (budgie DE) 17.10. I have used tons of things to make them work again. Setting up my keyboard (multiple times). Setting it up in the command line by being forwarded to the non-graphical keyboard installation (as root and non-root, just to be sure), trying different types of keyboards. The keys are still intact without any damages

Laptop: Acer E3-111-C9Gh

Specs: (probably won't matter, but just to be sure):

RAM: 3,7 GiB

Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2830 @ 2.16GHz × 2

Graphics: Intel® Bay Trail

64-bit

Disk: 320 GB, but I gave ubuntu a 206 GB partition

Thanks in advance!